# IBM x3650 M3 Server - can I just use a regular 2.5" SATA drive?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sas

IBM x3650 M3 Server - can I just use a regular 2.5" SATA drive? Or do they need to be a certain type?

Comment: I believe that this server uses SCSI disks as hot-swappable, but I'm not certain what the internal drives are. If it's using normal SATA ports, you can run a 2.5" disk on them, but I suspect that this is SCSI only.

Comment: I don't think they are SCSI? They look kind of like SATA connectors.

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely right. I was looking at the spec for an older x3650 model.

Answer (score 0):

As per the fine <strike>manual</strike> [product guide](https://lenovopress.com/tips0805-system-x3650-m3)

> Storage bay flexibility: Up to 16 hot-swap 2.5" drive bays for SAS or SATA HDDs, or solid-state drives (intermixing supported); or eight 2.5" bays plus an internal tape drive bay.

There's also a list of drives that were available which include [sata and SAS on the same page](https://lenovopress.com/tips0805-system-x3650-m3#internal-drive-options)

As such, a sata drive should work in any of the bays of that system

Comment: Except they dont.  Going off the same product data, I purchased 3 1TB ssd's.  They dont plug into the drive bay correctly..  Some sort of adapter is needed to go from sas to sata.